# Formatting Errors when using cursor.execute()

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, psycopg2

This is a section of code that is causing me troubles

```
def process_message( msg):
    # deserialize msg
    id_dict = json.loads(msg)
    # extract id

    report_id = id_dict['id']
    print report_id
    sql = """ select  r.id,
            format('DATA "the_geom from (%s) as subquery
            using unique gid using srid=4326"', replace(replace(sql,'<<','%%'),'>>','%%')) as data,
            rcode,
            format('  VALIDATION
            ''userid'' ''^\d+$''
%s
  END',string_agg(format ('    ''%s'' ''%s''', paramname, prompt[1]),'
')) as validation
FROM report.reports r
JOIN report.reportparams rp on r.id = rp.reportid and not rp.del
where r.id = %s
group by r.id, sql, rcode;"""
    args = ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')
    cursor.execute(sql, args)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    (id,data,rcode,validation) = row
    print (id,data,rcode,validation)
    exit
```

When running the code, this is the error message that appears

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mapfile_queue_processor.py", line 60, in <module>
    process_message(  content  )
  File "mapfile_queue_processor.py", line 41, in process_message
    cursor.execute(sql, args)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: type "s" does not exist
LINE 2:             format('DATA "the_geom from ('%s') as subquery
                                                   ^
```

Now I have tried a few different fixes based on what people have previously suggested but none are working.

In the sql variable, I have tried setting all the `%s` to `%%s` and to `'%s'` and to `'%%s'` and to `"%s"` and to `"%%s"` and even to `{s}` for the hell of it

The only possible solution that I seem to have found is that I cannot have `args = ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')` and I need to have actual arguments rather than `'%s'`

Is this the solution to my problem?
And if so how do I go about it?

If not the solution, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The `args` parameter in cursor.execute() is supposed to be your real arguments to be passed to the query (they will take the place of `%s` placeholders).

Answer (score 0):

In `cursor.execute()` your args should contain the real arguments (the values) you want to replace in your query, not '%s'. As [said in the documentation](http://pythonhosted.org//psycopg2/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) :

Psycopg casts Python variables to SQL literals by type. Many standard Python types are already adapted to the correct SQL representation.

Example: the Python function call:

```
>>> cur.execute(
...     """INSERT INTO some_table (an_int, a_date, a_string)
...         VALUES (%s, %s, %s);""",
...     (10, datetime.date(2005, 11, 18), "O'Reilly"))
```

is converted into the SQL command:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (an_int, a_date, a_string)
 VALUES (10, '2005-11-18', 'O''Reilly');
```

Named arguments are supported too using %(name)s placeholders. Using named arguments the values can be passed to the query in any order and many placeholders can use the same values:

```
>>> cur.execute(
...     """INSERT INTO some_table (an_int, a_date, another_date, a_string)
...         VALUES (%(int)s, %(date)s, %(date)s, %(str)s);""",
...     {'int': 10, 'str': "O'Reilly", 'date': datetime.date(2005, 11, 18)})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use parameter binding (ie '%s' handled by psycopg) to do the placeholder substitution in your quoted inner query. You will have to build some of the query string yourself, escaping every '%' you want to end up verbatim in the query.

```
sql = "select 'Hello, %s' from bobs where id = %%s" % ("Bob",)
cursor.execute( sql, [123] )
```

Obviously you'll need to sanitize your parameters - I think psycopg has some functions available for this.